# Issue with enabling AWS cross-acount reads + writes while having bucket owner retain ownership over all objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I need AWS accounts A, B to have read + write access to bucket Q in account C. However, account C should have full ownership over all objects in bucket Q. In line with these [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-require-object-ownership/), I added the following permissions policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        // WRITE PERMISSIONS
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    // Account A
                    "arn:aws:iam::<Account A ID>:root",
                    // Account B
                    "arn:aws:iam::<Account B ID>:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            // Bucket Q
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket Q name>/*",
            // Basically, all writes must supply bucket-owner-full-control as the ACL or they will be rejected
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        // READ PERMISSION for account A
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account A ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket Q name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket Q name>/*"
            ]
        },
        // READ PERMISSION for account B
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account B ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket Q name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket Q name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, writes (e.g. `s3.meta.client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=data, ACL='bucket-owner-full-control')`) fail with `ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`. What am I missing? If it matters at all, writes are being issued from a SageMaker notebook in account B.

Comment: Does the role you use to run that s3 command have any / the correct s3 permissions? Is the bucket encrypted and you need to grant access to the KMS key as well?

Comment: @luk2302 No encryption on the bucket. How can I figure out which role the notebook is using to make the API call?

Comment: @luk2302 thanks the for the help, I needed to add permissions to the role.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- Attach a resource policy to the IAM role that the SageMaker notebook uses. This policy should give the role `s3:putObject` and `s3:putObjectAcl` permissions (i.e. the same permissions the bucket policy lists). You can find the role that the SageMaker notebook uses by viewing your notebook instance in the SageMaker UI.
- Attach an identity policy to the IAM role that the SageMaker notebook uses. This policy should allow the account root to assume the role.

In my case, the resource policy was:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket Q name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the identity policy was

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account B ID>:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
 }
```